# React hot toast: useState reading properties of null

Tags: reactjs, react-hot-toast

I'm trying to use react-hot-toast library in my project.
Following the Getting Started guide on their NPM [site](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) I've:

- installed the library,
- imported toast and Toaster,
- added notify function,
- added the div with button and Toaster.

```
import toast, { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast';

const notify = () => toast('Here is your toast.');

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={notify}>Make me a toast</button>
      <Toaster />
    </div>
  );
};
```

After running my app I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ2uM.png). Commenting out the Toaster makes the error go away, but then the toasts don't work (obviously...).

I've tried:

- explicitly specifying toastOptions -> same error,
- moving the Toaster to other parts of app (index.jsx, app.jsx) -> same error,
- using different library (react-toastify) -> same behaviour, but with useReducer error. Toastify also doesn't show the error after commenting out ToastContainer (equivalent to Toaster).

I'm most concerned about the last point, which makes it pretty obvious, that the problem is something in my app structure. But this is my first project in react and I'm not sure how to approach resolving it.

One last additional info that could be relevant: I've installed several libraries to this project (fullcalendar, momentjs...). They all work fine. I've tried to install three new during last 7 days (react-hot-toast, react-toastify, i18n). None of them work because of useState/useReducer errors.

Thanks for any help or tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone in my situation - if you have separate package.json files and node_modules folders for frontend and backend, don't spend the whole weekend trying to debug a well working code. Instead, check the current folder opened in terminal when installing the library.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In this case, trying the package in a code sandbox is a good idea.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-hill-b8fbfc?file=/src/App.js) I have set it up for you; as you can see, it works just fine.

So the problem is not with the toast component.
Do you have some more code or is this the whole project?

Comment: Thanks a lot. As expected, there was no problem with the library. I forgot to switch between folders when using npm install (backend and frontend are separate), so I installed it to BE and FE could not access it. Hence the reading null errors.